# ID последней вставленной записи

Tags: ооп, php, yii, mysql

У меня два вопроса. Пожалуйста, помогите хоть с одним.
Первый вопрос: как узнать ID последней вставленной записи?

Есть код:

```
// Добавляем новую запись в таблицу 
mysql_query('INSERT INTO users SET name="Nick"'); 
// Определяем идентификатор последней добавленной записи в этой таблице 
$latest_id = mysql_insert_id(); 
print 'Самая последняя запись имеет ID: '.$latest_id;
```

НО проблема в том, что после запроса инсерт до команды mysql_insert_id() любое количество инсертов может выполнится, и код здесь не уместен, данная функция показывает последнее ИД вставленной записи не таблицы, а БД, т.е. какая последняя запись была вставлена в одну из таблиц БД, та и выводится.
Вопрос номер два: и самое главное нужно реализовать для ООП, а именно для фреймворка yii. Пока это выглядит так:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `users` (`name`) VALUES ('Nick')";
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

id только вставленной таблицы в yii можно так:

```
Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID()
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь модель User,
а дальше

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "Nick";
if(!$user->save())
    throw new Exception("Failed create new user!");
```